# Reclassifying in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to build a model to iterate between land cover raster files and reclassify them. However when I open the Reclassify tool, the remap section has been greyed out. I'm assuming I somehow need to collect the values in the raster file first to input them into the reclassify tool but I don't know how to do this.

Each raster file has the same values (just represent different years) and I want to reclassify those values the same way for each raster file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Pro are you using, your simple model worked for me? Also what format and bit depth are your rasters?

Comment: @Hornbydd version 2.9.0 - TIFF and 32 bit

Comment: Hmm ok, not sure what to suggest. Model builder can do odd things, sometimes it is easier to simply abandon the model and start a new one?

Comment: Raster statistics absent?

Comment: @FelixIP How would I collect raster statistics in the ModelBuilder? I somehow need to have the Model identify all the values in the Value field that I want to reclassify

Comment: Give it up. Create reclassification table once and use it as input to reclassification by table. Some latest improvements in reclass tool made it a big pain to work with even in gui

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Reclassify tool in your model, then click Create Variable, then From Parameter.  Choose Reclassification.

[image]

This gives you a Reclassification parameter you can modify.

[image]

Comment: I thought that would have worked but unfortunately I can't edit the reclassification parameter (screenshot added to original post). These are all .tif files.

Comment: Does it give you the ability to edit if you connect one of the rasters directly to the Reclassify tool first? I remember stuff like this is why I forced myself to pickup some python experience, because as noted above, ModelBuilder really does strange things at times.  If you can connect a raster (not the recursive object) to Reclassify, see if that lets you set the reclassification values in the parameter.  Then plug the recursive object back in and see if the values are preserved.